# Heatmap changes to single color when zooming out in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, style, heat-map

Working with QGIS 3.28, I have a point layer with several million points. Using heatmap renderer, I get the left heatmap with these settings:

- scale 1.100.000
- radius 200 meters at scale
- Maximum value: Automatic

With the same settings an without changing anything but scale (zooming out), at scale 1:400.000, the whole heatmaps appears in a single color, the "first" one (coror on the left of the color ramp).

So both images look completely different, even using real world distances: why is that?

*Left image - scale 1:100.000; right image - scale 1:400.000, rest of setting are the same. Black frame indicates the extent of the first zoom level:*
[image]

As far as I understand, my settings mean that every point on the map canvas gets assigned a value: the number of points within 200 meters - this value refering to real-world distances (I use a prjected CRS apt for measurements). So the colors should remain the same when zooming out as I do not use units referring to the screen, but to real world.

Changing from Meters at scale to Map units does not change anything, same problem.

Comment: Did you try to set a Maximum value rather than using automatic ? I did try on QGIS 3.28 and I get the expected result with both automatic and a fixed maximum value but my test data has only 2000 point maybe your million points are to many for the automatic setting)

Comment: With a radius of 1000 and maximum set to automatic, I get a heatmap. Trying different values, the problem seems to be the radius, not the maximum settings. Increasing the radius makes the heatmap appear, indifferent if max. is set to automatic or any number.

Comment: OK, I get the same effect as you with my test data and a smaller radius, what happen is that as you zoom out the darker color blob get smaller (as it should) when you keep zooming out it reach a point where each blob is only one pixel then if I zoom out more they disappear. The same thing happen with all symbology type if you use "Meters at Scale" or "Map Units" for size, as you zoom out you eventually reach a point where feature are to small to be displayed...

Comment: But I agree that in the case of the Heatmap renderer this causes a problem as the "0" color (in your case pale red) is still visible while other value are considered to small to appear. not sure what QGIS should do in this situation, display nothing ? show a warning ?